# How can I cause a dummy notification in Android 6.0?

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to set my phone up so that notifications won't show up in certain situations. To test my set-up, I need to create a notification myself, so I can see whether it shows up or not.

What's the easiest way to create a fake or dummy notification, without having to write an app to do it?

Comment: It's not clear- what is causing the notification in first place( apps, I suppose), where is it being displayed normally? what exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe, a snapshot in addition to explanation would help

Comment: You Could try [macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en). **Trigger:** Notification received (from any app); **Action**: 1.Clear notifications 2. Display Dialog (whatever you wish to be displayed) **Constraints :** none (run always). In the display dialog, you can configure for a number of things, like app sending notification, time etc...see options

Comment: I think I understood what you're trying to do. Other people haven't, and your question was at risk of being closed as "unclear". I've edited it to try to make it clear, but if my edit isn't right, you should [edit] it yourself and make it clearer.

Comment: Send yourself an email and you'll get a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for this?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

It turned out that major [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps can easily do this, at least [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) ([free trial](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html); [user guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/)), [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) and [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) can.

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

**Note:**

- In Tasker, Action to create a notification from a task is available under *Alert* action category.

  **Test run**: use the play button in the main window of the task.
- In MacroDroid, the Action is named *Display Notification*.

  **Test run**: long press your macro and choose *Test Actions*.
- In Automate, the block *Notification show* under Interface category can create notification. For that block, *Proceed* should be set to *When dismissed*.

  **Test run**: press *Start* in the default window of the flow.
- In each of the the said apps, you need not to assign a trigger at all.

It might become tedious if you're to create the dummy notification multiple times, so I suggest you try an app which can execute an app shortcut with convenience, such as:

- [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150); or
- a gesture specific app such as [GMD Gesture Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontrol) and [All in one Gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures) (both may require root access); or perhaps
- bind the shortcut to a hardware key using 
  [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) (requires root access and [compatible Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811))

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: I think this is the best solution so long as there is no default way to do it with the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Install the DO app: https://ifttt.com/products/do/button. Inside it create a DO recipe using a channel called 'IF notifications'. Set a message and you're ready to go - every time you'll hit that button, a notification will be posted. Tip - you can enable a floating button for this recipe too to make it more accessible.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually point out a specific one.

Comment: Yeah my bad - got more details in now :)

Answer (score -1):

Another approach install Pushbullet on your phone and PC/browser. Then whenever you push from the other device, you'll get a notification on your phone :)